# For each Error Handling on Validation

Tags: php, foreach

I have a php registration form. If validation fails it would generate an error message contained in one or more of the following:

```
$_SESSION['error']['firstname']
$_SESSION['error']['lastname']
$_SESSION['error']['username']
$_SESSION['error']['email']
$_SESSION['error']['password']
$_SESSION['error']['country']
```

On form submission i have some code which says :

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['error']))
{
   echo '<p>'.$_SESSION['error']['firstname'].'</p>';
   echo '<p>'.$_SESSION['error']['lastname'].'</p>';
   echo '<p>'.$_SESSION['error']['username'].'</p>';
   echo '<p>'.$_SESSION['error']['email'].'</p>';
   echo '<p>'.$_SESSION['error']['password'].'</p>';
   echo '<p>'.$_SESSION['error']['country'].'</p>';
   unset($_SESSION['error']);      
}

?>
```

This code will echo the error message for the invalid submission. I realise my code is wrong because if there is no error for one of the SESSION errors then it would be undefined. Is there a way i can create a 'foreach' for each error that isset echo the error?

Comment: Yes there is a way of using foreach, what part are you having a problem with? `foreach($_SESSION['error'] as $error) { ... }`

Comment: <?php
       if(isset($_SESSION['error']))
      {
          foreach($_SESSION['error'] as $error) 
          {
              echo '<p>'.$error.'</p>'; 
              unset($_SESSION['error']);
          }
       }
?>

Has done the trick thank you very much, I've been looking for the correct way to do this for ages. I'm a complete noob when it comes to php and mysqli.